# How to create a sampler in OTEL that filters by URL in javascript/TS

Tags: otel

I have implemented head-based sampling based on [an example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/blob/8786cbe7163e552a4d9fc39609188236fd66c780/plugins/node/opentelemetry-instrumentation-express/examples/src/tracer.ts).

But since the URL (`attributes['http.url']`) is not know at span creation time that doesn't work for me.

I cannot find any documentation on how to code your own tail-based sampler either.